# Java , Modular Inverse

Tags: java, encryption, modular

i have some mathematique function to do (for affine encryption) am looking for the Modular Inverse
for exemple 
the modular inverse of A=5 and an alphabet of length 26 is 21
i have worked with this solution (A' =(n % 26 + 26) % 26) but it gives a wrong solution i need some help please :/

Answer (score 1):

T = total elements in the set.

N = the number for which you want the "mod inverse".

I = the mod inverse.

I = T - (N % T)